# run .deb package created by fpm

Tags: permissions, software-installation, package-management, dpkg, deb

I created a `.deb` package with [fpm](https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/v1.13.1/). The package is very simple as it simply runs a [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) over [this](https://diagnosticator.com/download/docker-compose.yml) `docker-compose.yml` file.

The package is composed of 3 files:

```bsh
.
├── diagnosticator
├── diagnosticator.1
└── docker-compose.yml
```

The permissions on `diagnosticator` are as follows:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 enrico enrico 554 feb 12 21:23 diagnosticator
```

Here is my `diagnosticator` script, that simply needs to run the `docker-compose.yml`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#
# == diagnosticator 0.1.0 ==
#

DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE=/usr/lib/diagnosticator/docker-compose.yml

if [ -s $DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE ]; then
  docker-compose pull && docker-compose up
else
  echo ' !!! ERROR !!!'
  echo ' ---> missing docker-compose.yml <--- '
fi

exit 0
```

and here the `fpm` command used to build it:

```bsh
fpm \
  -s dir -t deb \
  --deb-use-file-permissions \
  -p diagnosticator-0.1.0-1-any.deb \
  --name diagnosticator \
  --license agpl3 \
  --version 0.1.0 \
  --architecture all \
  --depends bash \
  --description "Diagnosticator local app" \
  --url "https://diagnosticator.com" \
  --maintainer "Enrico Cocchi" \
  diagnosticator=/usr/bin/diagnosticator diagnosticator.1=/usr/share/man/man1/diagnosticator.1 docker-compose.yml=/usr/lib/diagnosticator/docker-compose.yml
```

When I `sudo dpkg -i diagnosticator-0.1.0-1-any.deb` everything works fine and files get placed where they should, but if I try to run it (with and without `sudo`):

```
$ diagnosticator
bash: /usr/bin/diagnosticator: Permission denied

$ sudo diagnosticator
sudo: diagnosticator: command not found
```

I'd like users to be able to run it without `sudo`. I tried to google and search here for any solutions but I could not find any. Does anybody know what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `diagnosticator` script needs to be executable: run

```
chmod 755 diagnosticator
```

and build your package again.