# fpm .deb package docker dependencies

Tags: software-installation, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, fpm

I created a simple `.deb` package with [fpm](https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/v1.13.1/). The package is very basic and it simply runs a [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file (see my other question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/690321/run-deb-package-created-by-fpm) for package description).

I tried to specify that the package needs [docker](https://www.docker.com) and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) with:

```bsh
fpm \
  -s dir -t deb \
  --deb-use-file-permissions \
  -p diagnosticator-0.1.0-1-any.deb \
  --name diagnosticator \
  --license agpl3 \
  --version 0.1.0 \
  --architecture all \
  --depends bash \
  --depends docker \
  --depends docker-compose \
  --description "Diagnosticator local app" \
  --url "https://diagnosticator.com" \
  --maintainer "Enrico Cocchi" \
  diagnosticator=/usr/bin/diagnosticator diagnosticator.1=/usr/share/man/man1/diagnosticator.1 docker-compose.yml=/usr/lib/diagnosticator/docker-compose.yml
```

but if I try to install it with `sudo dpkg -i diagnosticator-0.1.0-1-any.deb`:

```bsh
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of diagnosticator:
 diagnosticator depends on docker; however:
  Package docker is not installed.
 diagnosticator depends on docker-compose; however:
  Package docker-compose is not installed.
```

even if I have both installed and working for my user:

```
$ which docker
/usr/bin/docker

$ which docker-compose
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package dependencies are on package names, not binaries.

For `docker`, you can determine the appropriate package name by running

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/docker
```

For `docker-compose`, you might need to create your own package first, or switch to [the relevant package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/docker-compose).

You might also want to install your package using `apt install ./diagnosticator-0.1.0-1-any.deb` instead of `dpkg -i`; that will try to resolve dependencies for you. Note too that your package file name should be `diagnosticator_0.1.0-1_all.deb`.

Comment: Thank you so much @StephenKitt for this answer. Would it be sufficient to put `DOCKER_COMPOSE=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose; sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o $DOCKER_COMPOSE && sudo chmod +x $DOCKER_COMPOSE` in my `diagnosticator` script (which are the instructions for docker-compose installation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) and add `curl` as dependency? Otherwise, how can I build my own package for `docker-compose`?

Comment: `sudo apt install docker-compose` should give you a working `/usr/bin/docker-compose`; I suggest you use that (so the dependency in your package *would* be on `docker-compose`).